# Contour Integrating

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

$$ I = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{2} \left( e^{-2vz - 2b\sinh(z)}\cos\left(\pi\left(\frac{1}{4} + v\right)\right) + e^{2vz - 2b\sinh(z)}\sin\left(\pi\left(\frac{1}{4} + v\right)\right) \right)}{\sqrt{e^z - e^{-z}}} \, \mathrm{d}z $$
Going through Desmos, the function does converge.$f(z)$, the integrand, is holomorphic in its domain, and the limits at $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ give me zero as long as $v \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\text{Re}(b) > 0$.

**Edit**:
As FShrike had mentioned, there's a branch cut at $0$. This is the reason for the keyhole contour. For further context, see the comments.
I wanted to also first show the Proof of Convergence from Desmos and two interesting cases of the integral. [image: proof of convergence]
$$\\$$
Case 1:
If I have $I(b)$ equal to the integral and vary $v$, I get close similarities to the Modified Bessel Function of the Second Kind.
[image: Case 1:]
$$\\$$
Case 2: If I have $I(v)$ equal to the integral, and vary $b$, the graph and its properites can be seen below.
[image: Case 2]
$\\$
I also wanted to provide an alternative contour that might work as well. After realization, there's a branch cut at $z=i\pi$ as well.

Also, as I tested equivalencies for the bounds of the integral, I got these odd results:
[image: Bounds of Integral]

**Note**:
This might not be necessary but may aid in a solution, here's how the integral behaves under various values of $v$ and $b$
[image: Behavior of Integral]

**Question:**
If stated correctly, the contour integral evaluates to 0 due to Cauchy's Integral Theorem. However, the path integrals of the contour would have to be evaluated. How would you evaluate the path integrals and evaluate the integral with the given notes above?
$$
\oint_{c} \frac{{\sqrt{2} \times (e^{-2vz - 2b\sinh(z)}\cos(\pi(1/4 + v)) + e^{2vz - 2b\sinh(z)}\sin(\pi(1/4 + v)))}}{{\sqrt{e^z - e^{-z}}}} \, dz
$$
Using the contour

$$
\oint_c = \lim_{{R \to \infty, \epsilon \to 0}} \left( \int_{\Gamma} + \int_{-R}^{-\epsilon} + \int_{\psi} + \int_{\epsilon}^{R} \right) $$
And with what I had stated:
$$ 0 =\lim_{{R \to \infty, \epsilon \to 0}} \left( \int_{\Gamma} + \int_{-R}^{-\epsilon} + \int_{\psi} + \int_{\epsilon}^{R} \right) $$
Please excuse my drawing as I am not an artist,
Keyhole Contour:

[Choosen Contour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlSnD.png)

[Alternative Contour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixLRP.jpg)

**Progress Made**
$$
\lim_{{R \to \infty \atop \epsilon \to 0}} \left(\int_{-R}^{-\epsilon} + \int_{\epsilon}^{R}\right)$$
$\\$
Which is equal to: $\int_{-\infty}^{0} + I$. And in connection to my notes:  $I=-\int_{-\infty}^{0} f(z) dz$.
Now, things get messy, so I'll keep it concise.
$\\$
Evaluating: $\int_{-\infty}^{0} f(z) \, dz$
$\\$
First I made the substitution $ w = e^{z},dw = e^{z} \, dz $.
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{b(1/w-w)}w^{-1-2v}\left(\cos \left(\pi \left(\frac{1}{4}+v\right)\right)+w^{4v}\sin \left(\pi \left(\frac{1}{4}+v\right)\right) \right)}{\sqrt{-\frac{1}{w}+w}} dw $$
Distribute the $\pi$, use the sum and difference formulas for $\cos$ and $\sin$, and distribute throughout.
Next I factor out $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ which cancels out
At this point, the integral is:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\left(e^{-bw + \frac{b}{w}} w^{(-1 - 2v)}\cos(\pi v) - e^{-bw + \frac{b}{w}} w^{(2v - 1)}\cos(\pi v)\right) + \left(-e^{-bw + \frac{b}{w}} w^{(-1 - 2v)}\sin(\pi v) + e^{-bw + \frac{b}{w}} w^{(2v - 1)}\sin(\pi v)\right)}{\sqrt{w - w^{-1}}} \, dw$$
Split into two fractions,
$$I_{1} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(\pi v) e^{-bw + \frac{b}{w}} (w^{-1 - 2v} - w^{2v - 1})}{\sqrt{w - w^{-1}}} dw$$
And,
$$I_{2}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\left(\pi v\right)e^{-bw+\frac{b}{w}}\left(w^{\left(-1-2v\right)}+w^{\left(2v-1\right)}\right)}{\sqrt{w-w^{-1}}}dw$$
Therefore, $I=-(I_1+I_2)$
I have also assumed both path integrals evaluate to zero. However, I'm uncertain.

Comment: The square root makes this not holomorphic on the whole complex plane, watch out for that

Comment: @FShrike I was careful to do so, hence the line on Riemann Theorem, unless there's other constraints that need to be added.

Comment: The square root is not holomorphic on $D\setminus\{a\}$ if $a$ lies on the branch cut, so the theorem isn't applicable

Comment: @FShrike If I didn't have that constraint and chose a contour, f(z) would still be holomorphic, I believe. So Cauchy Theorem would still apply.

Comment: You have to choose a branch cut for the square root, think about when the $e^z-e^{-z}$ is on a branch cut, draw a contour that suitably avoids this (or cleverly exploits it). Notice you haven't defined "$c$" at all, which is a problem!

Comment: @Fshrike I added it thank you! The problem is now the path integrals